# SQL Split Month Data in to Days Date rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, recursive-query

I have a table in SQL Server with Monthly target units.

```
select TargetDate, Units
FROM TargetTable;

TargetDate  Units
2020-01-01  62
2020-02-01  87
2020-03-01  104
2020-04-01  109
```

I want the Units by dates - dividing total units by number of days in that month - and having rows with days and daily units... something like this:

```
TargetDate  Units
2020-01-01  2
2020-01-02  2
2020-01-03  2
2020-01-04  2
    .
    .
    .
2020-02-01  3
```

I understand SQL at a beginner level, and would be grateful for any help here.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a recusive query:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        targetdate, 
        eomonth(targetdate) enddate, 
        1.0 * units / day(eomonth(targetdate)) units
    from targettable
    union all
    select dateadd(day, 1, targetdate), enddate, units 
    from cte
    where targetdate < enddate
)
select targetdate, units from cte
```

Notes:

- I assume that the `units` will not always be a multiple of the number of days in the month, so this gives you a decimal value rather than an integer.
- If you need to handle more than 100 days (about 3 months of data), then you need to add `option (max recursion 0)` at the end of the query.
- `eomonth()` was introduced in SQL Server 2012 (there are alternatives in earlier versions)

Comment: `OPTION(MAXRECUSION 0)` won't be needed. There are no months that have over 100  days. :)

Comment: Thanks... but I am getting the following error: Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "TargetDate" of recursive query "cte".
 Units are not always multiples, and I am fine with the decimals.

Comment: @chhibbz: then I imagine that `targetdate` is not of a `date`-like datatype. Jusst replace the first occurence of `targetdate` with `cast(targetdate as date)`, and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  targetDate, 
  DATEADD(day, a, targetDate) as dd, 
  CAST(units as FLOAT) / DAY(EOMONTH(targetdate)) as uu

FROM 
    ( 
        VALUES 
        (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),
        (10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),
        (20),(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30)
    ) a(a)

    CROSS JOIN

    /*
    (SELECT CAST('2020-01-01' as date) targetdate, 62 as units  UNION ALL 
     SELECT CAST('2020-02-01' as date), 87 UNION ALL 
     SELECT CAST('2020-03-01' as date), 104
    )x*/
    targetTable

WHERE 
   DATEADD(day, a, targetdate) <= EOMONTH(targetdate)
```

How it works:

We generate a block of numbers from 0 to 30, and cross your existing data with them, giving 31 repetitions of 2020-01-01, 31 reps of 2020-02-01, 31 reps of 2020-03-01 etc.

```
2020-01-01, 0
2020-01-01, 1
2020-01-01, 2
...
```

If we add the number (as days) to the date it gives a date that rolls up through the month but some dates overshoot into the next month:

```
2020-01-01, 0, 2020-01-01
2020-01-01, 1, 2020-01-02
2020-01-01, 2, 2020-01-03
...
2020-02-01, 28, 2020-02-29
2020-02-01, 29, 2020-03-01 --it's march!
2020-02-01, 30, 2020-03-02 --it's march!
```

We use a where clause to cut out dates that overshoot by making sure our added date is less than or equal to the EOMONTH(targetdate) - EOMONTH returns a date that is the last day of the month for the date passed in

So we've got the incrementing date, and we just need the units per day - divide the units by the number of the days in the month (given by the day of the EOMONTH(targetdate) ). We cast units to float so that sqlserver will do the division with decimals rather than ints (otherwise 60/31 is 1)

If you don't have a `EOMONTH` function you can use `DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1 targetdate))` to roll forwards a month and back a day